# Using a custom css with react bootstrap and webpack

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am trying to to use this theme (http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/landing-page/) with React and have replaced the `homepage/node_modules/bootstrap` files with the ones provided, but it is still reading from the original CSS files. Do you know how I can get this to work?

My repo: https://github.com/ammark47/homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate bundle.js with webpack. Import it in index.html. Again in the index, import all the necessary css files. Let webpack do the rest for you.

Comment: nope. webpack just replaces it with css from the default bootstrap css